# How can I save and load the content of HTML into the file using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a modal which contain table and have a save setup button and load setup button, When I click on save button the table content should be saved in a file in any folder in any format and by clicking on load button it should able to load that file in the HTML format.

So how can I do this?

below is the code for Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="envVarModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="text-align:center">Environment Variable Settings</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="envVarModalBodyID">
        <label>Env Variable:</label>
        <select  id="envVarID" name="Select2" onchange="addEnvVar()">
            <option value="nothingSelected">Select Env Variable</option>
            <option value="Count">Count</option>
            <option value="Schedule">Schedule</option>

        </select>
        <table><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr><tr><td>Three</td><td>Four</td></tr></table>"
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save Setup</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Load Setup</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add some details, please. You want to save exactly on file or you need just save data to restore it later?

Comment: Where is the state of your code? Do you still need to save and load the data to a file? You may want to search around for sending javascript data to php, and retrieving data from php. The rest is figuring out how you want to format the data so that you can read it later (I suggest JSON).

Comment: What my requirement is after making changes in the table or any field, I could be able to save the data in a file by clicking save button and by clicking on load button it should be able restore the data from the file later in the future.

Comment: What my requirement is after making changes in the table or any field, I could be able to save the data in a file by clicking save button and by clicking on load button it should be able restore the data from the file into the Modal in HTML format later in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript to save the table in .xls format.I have added on click event to your button

**btn btn-default** class
where you have to make the table contain in `<div id="table1">`your table structure`</div>`

```
<script>

    var tableToExcel = (function() {
      var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
      return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
      }
    })()
    </script>



    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="tableToExcel('table1', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
```

Comment: Actually there are some text fields not only table so how can I save the data some where in the file or in some other format so that i can restore it in future by clicking on load and the gui  should look same before saving it and after loading it.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?